# conditional replacement of special characters in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to be able to take a dataframe **df** containing a column **df$col** that has entries like:

```
I?m tired
You?re tired
You?re tired?
Are you tired?
?I am tired
```

and replace question marks that occur between letters with apostrophes and question marks that occur at the beginnings of strings with nothing:

```
I'm tired
You're tired
You're tired?
Are you tired?
I am tired
```

Comment: I'd use `gsub("(*UCP)(?<=\\p{L})\\?(?=\\p{L})", "'", sub("^\\?", "", df$col), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: could it be that it is an encoding problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `sub` for the question marks at the beginning and `gsub` for the others, because there could be several question marks between words in a string but only one at the beginning.

```
gsub("(\\w)\\?(\\w)", "\\1'\\2", sub("^\\?", "", df$col))
[1] "I'm tired"      "You're tired"   "You're tired?"  "Are you tired?"
[5] "I am tired"
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jClVPg/1 for some explanation.

Some explanation:

- 1st Capturing Group (\\w):

  \\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- \\? matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Capturing Group (\\w):

  \\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

Comment: what do the w's signify in this?

Comment: The signify word characters

Comment: okay cool, that's what I figured. Thank you!

Comment: @soosus Word chars are digits, letters and `_` symbols. If you only want to consider letters, replace both `\\w` with `[[:alpha:]]`, and with this approach, you will not be able to replace consecutive matches (i.e. cases like `S?a?m`, but I believe it should not be a problem here).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you find my answer insufficient you are welcome to post your own ideas/approach, too.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think it is sufficient, but lacks details explaining why the solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
df$col <- sub("^'", "", sub("[?](?!$)", "'", df$col, perl = TRUE))
df$col
#[1] "I'm tired"      "You're tired"   "You're tired?"  "Are you tired?" "I am tired"
```

Here we assume that there will be a single `?` as showed in the example.  Otherwise, just replace the inner `sub` with `gsub`

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("I?m tired", "You?re tired", "You?re tired?", 
"Are you tired?", "?I am tired")), .Names = "col", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: This one doesn't quite do it; it replaces question marks at the ends of strings with apostrophes. Thank you though!

Comment: @soosus I am not getting what you are saying.  I get the output as you showed in your post